# How can I improve this equation so items with more negative votes than positive return a more useful Wilson Score

Tags: python, math, statistics

Using the Wilson Score equation described here http://www.evanmiller.org/how-not-to-sort-by-average-rating.html , I am sorting my rated items. However, if an item has 1 negative vote (and 0 positive votes), it returns the same score (that being a score of 0) as an item with 1000 negative votes (and 0 positive).

**I'd like to either allow a negative Wilson Score, to overcome this shortcoming, or perhaps another solution someone may suggest.**

Either way, **I am not sure how to alter this equation/function**:

```
def ci_lower_bound(pos, n, confidence):
    if n==0: return 0

    z = 1.96
    phat = 1.0*pos/n

    score = (phat + z*z/(2*n) - z*math.sqrt((phat*(1-phat)+z*z/(4*n))/n))/(1+z*z/n)
    return score
```

where `pos` is the number of positive ratings, `n` is the total number of ratings, `confidence` refers to the statistical confidence level.

Comment: Do you know the number of positive _and_ negative scores or just the total?

Comment: @Ben yes, I have total, positive, and negative scores

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logically, your scoring system has to deal with the following situations:

```
+----------+----------+------------+---------------+
| Positive | Negative | Any Votes? | Wilson Score? |
+----------+----------+------------+---------------+
| N        | N        | N          | Y, = 0        |
| Y        | Y        | Y          | Y             |
| Y        | N        | Y          | Y             |
| N        | Y        | Y          | N             |
+----------+----------+------------+---------------+
```

The missing item being when you have 0 positive votes and more than 0 negative votes, as you note.

As you have both positive and negative scores at the time, why not follow your own idea and create a negative Wilson Score to deal with this, remembering that the square root of a negative number is complex.

To get around complexity assume that negative votes are positive. You then calculate how "liked" a negatively scored item is and multiple this by -1 to turn it into how disliked it is.

```
import math

def ci_lower_bound(pos, n, neg=0):

    if n == 0:
        return 0

    # Cannot calculate the square-root of a negative number
    if pos == 0:
        votes, use_neg = neg, True
    else:
        votes, use_neg = pos, False


    # Confidence
    z = 1.96

    phat = 1.0 * votes / n

    # Calculate how confident we are that this is bad or good.
    score = (phat + z*z/(2*n) - z * math.sqrt((phat*(1-phat)+z*z/(4*n))/n))/(1+z*z/n)

    # This relationship is defined above.
    # Multiply by -1 to return a negative confidence.
    if use_neg:
        return -1 * score

    return score
```

Comment: what I've noticed is if there are more negative than positive votes, my original equation returns a `score` of 0. So the problem isn't only when there are 0 positive votes.

Comment: @Raj, you're meant to pass into the function the total number of _positive_ votes and the total number of votes. _Not_ the combined total! As long as there's 1 positive vote this should not return 0.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting to pass in the sum of _positive_ and _total_ votes. That makes no sense! :) What I'm saying is, with my original function (in the original question), I noticed that if any item had more negative votes than positive, the item ended up with a score of 0. And it didn't seem the solution you posted would prevent that. Am I correct?

Comment: What numbers are you passing in to get such a result? I'm fairly confident that it's impossible. Simplifying if you have more than one positive vote the square-root must be a positive number. Unless `phat + z * z / ( 2 * n )` is _exactly_ equal to the sqrt ( highly unlikely ), you shouldn't get 0 if you have _one_ or more positive votes.

Comment: sorry, what I described is not the case, I was mistaken. However, with your code, 1 upvote and 1 downvote gives a score of -0.09452865480086611. Does that seem okay?

Comment: @Raj, it is right, just the code was wrong. I hadn't taken into account whether you were using a negative number or not properly. It's fixed now - and slightly uglier because of it.

Comment: What do you mean using a negative number or not properly? What would using it properly entail, and what would using it improperly entail? BTW, thank you very much for your time and explanations on this, it's been **very** helpful!

Comment: Maybe poorly phrased :-): I hadn't properly taken into account whether you were using a negative number or not; and no problem!

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could always sort by the tuple `(wilsonscore, -negative_votes)`, because of the way python sorts tuples.
Python never considers the negative_votes, except for when the wilsonscore is identical.
See:

```
>>> sorted([(0,-4000),(1,-4000),(0,-1),(1,-1)])
[(0, -4000), (0, -1), (1, -4000), (1, -1)]
```

pro: simple solution to the problem, no need to alter the function, and very few need to alter code at all (since tuples behave "natural" when sorted).

cons: need to keep track of negative votes.

Comment: I am returning a `rating` variable from `ci_lower_bound()`. And then this variable is used in a very complicated sorting method that sorts by multiple sortkeys in quite a complicated fashion. Without making significant changes to the code, I would not be able to implement this, and therefore just need the `rating` number itself to reflect an item's position in the sorting order.